# Meaning of "\\" in flex - scanner generator

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I'm reading a [Start Conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html#Start-Conditions) of the flex manual. Below is part of an example that is given on this page:

```
<str>\n        {
                 /* error - unterminated string constant */
                 /* generate error message */
               }
...
<str>\\n  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\n';
...
```

What is the difference between **\n** and **\\n**?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `\n` matches a newline character (normally `Ox0A`). The rule triggers if a C-style quoted string is not terminated before a newline is reached, which it treats as an error.
- `\\n` matches a backslash followed by the letter `n`. The rule is triggered if the quoted string includes the two-character sequence `\n`, which it replaces with a single newline character. (There should also be rules for the six other C-style letter-escape sequences, `\a`, `\b`,`\f`, `\r`, `\t`, and `\v` -- each substituted with the appropriate control character -- but for reasons I can't attest to, two of them are missing.)

Comment: The page has 5 of the 6 mentioned.  `\v` is rarely used, easily overlooked.